# Promises and arrays in Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, foreach, promise

I am using Bluebird and request npm packages:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = Promise.promisify(require('request'));
Promise.promisifyAll(request);
```

I have a function that goes out to a REST endpoint and returns some data:

```
var getData = function() {
    options.url = 'http://my/endpoint';
    options.method = 'GET'; //etc etc...
    return request(options);
};

getData().then(function(response) {
  console.log(response); //-> this returns an array
});
```

`response` is an array that gets returned by the REST endpoint. The problem is that now I'd like to make a second request for each item in my array, so something like:

```
var getIndividualData = function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    options.url = 'http://my/endpoint/d'; //make individual requests for each item
    return request(options);
  });
};
```

The above of course does not work and I understand why. However, what I don't understand is how can I make this work. Ideally what I'd like to have is a chain such as:

```
getData().then(function(response) {
  return getIndividualData(response);
}).then(function(moreResponse) {
  console.log(moreResponse); // the result of the individual calls produced by getIndividualData();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Promise.all](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#all---promise) to wait for an array of promises to complete.

```
getData()
  .then(getIndividualData)
  .then(function(moreResponse) {
    // the result of the individual calls produced by getIndividualData();
    console.log(moreResponse);
   });

function getIndividualData(list) {
  var tasks = list.map(function(item) {
    options.url = // etc.
    return request(options);
  });

  return Promise.all(tasks);
}
```